# Difference between GetObject and New

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

I usually create an Excel (or ppt) object like:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Private _xlApp as Excel.Application

_xlApp = CType(GetObject(, "Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
...
```

now checking something on msdn I saw in an example they are doing it this way:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Officee.Interop.Excel

Dim xlApp as Excel.Application = Nothing
xlApp = New Excel.Application
```

Could anyone explain the difference between these two methods since I want to apply it right and cannot see the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the first case, you're just getting a COM object by name and casting it to its own Type. really only useful to instance objects from a file library which isn't registered for COM interop, or to get some other object from a file. i suppose you can also use it to get the instance of a running application.

hmm, it seems you can load excel files as objects directly from file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

in the second case, you're just referencing the managed interop library and creating the object directly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aax7sdch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! "from a file library which isn't registered for COM interop" what is a non-registered COM interop library? A selfwritten interface to excel (in my case?). So, do I understand that right that in my case (a registered interop) it is useless to use the GetObject()-Method?

Comment: well, it's a roundabout method, and limited in scope. personally, i would use something like: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx although they both accomplish the same thing, one is just simpler than the other.

Comment: hmm, there's a bug related to office interop specifically, with it not registering in the ROT. but those articles are dated (from 2003-2005). not sure if they still apply. if you scroll to the bottom of that article, in the user comments.

Comment: also, you could use the CreateObject method to create it without having to reference the excel interop library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx